# Can I use port 21 for two ip cameras to ftp to two different servers?

Tags: ftp

I am trying to send ip camera images from one camera via ftp to a weather site, ambientweather.net, and another ip camera to send images to another online webcam site, webcam.io.  I can do one or the other but my router, TP link AX6600 won't allow me to open port 21 to both cameras.  I know there may be other ways to get the images to these sites, but ftp is my preferred means.  I do not want to have to have a computer on all the time to accomplish this either.  Both sites appear to only use port 21 for this.  Any help is appreciated.  thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "open port 21"? If the camera can connect via the router, there are no limitations on how many connections a router can handle. Are you sure that this is indeed the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't your cameras make outgoing FTP connections? There should be no need to change *anything* on the router.

Comment: So questions about whether you should do this aside, you are correct, a standard home router cannot forward the same port for multiple devices. the general solution to this is to forward the port from a reverse proxy, and then let the proxy decide which of the devices is being requested using a hostname. this is non-trivial for a novice and requires additional infrastructure.

Comment: harry, I'm not sure about anything at this point.  I had originally set up port forward on first camera to get to ftp site, thinking this was a problem since ambientweather.net was sometimes connecting with my camera and sometimes not.  It would connect and a few hours later stop sending/receiving.  Camera log showed no errors or anyting else that might point to issue.  I think it was/is the AW site.  I now have no port forwarding and initially the camera connected, was approved by AW and showed snapshots for several hours today, but at 15:01 stopped.

Comment: the question is does the website connect to the camera, or does the camera connect to the website?

Comment: My camera was trying to connect to the AW website.  Sometimes it did, sometimes it wouldn't.  When it did, it worked for a few hours and stopped.  Other sites work fine.  I'm convinced that AW wants me to buy their camera.  I am senting camera data to another site now, without issue.  I'll have to figure out what to do about the AW site, as I would like to put up a weather camera, but alas, it may not be.

Comment: if the camera is connecting outbound through the router to the website, then you should not need any particular configuration on your router.

Comment: It is, I didn’t know any better at the time.  I have no port forwarding now and it’s working fine with other sites.